# Overriding back button press from Activity's subClass in Android

Tags: android

I'm making a game with OpenGL Es 1.1 and i want to implement back button or menu button functionality to my game.(I mean hardware buttons).I have some subClasses so what i have to do when i want to handle hardware button press from subClasses?

Comment: what do you mean that you are outside of the activity? You aren't extending Activity with anything in your project?

Comment: @Tim Yes i'm extending but how can i override an activity function in a subClass?

Comment: You should still be able to just the same... Post your code if you are having trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement an onKeyDown listener and check to see what key is pressed.

Sample:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent e) {
     switch(keycode) {
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
             handleMenuButton();
             return true;
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
             handleBackButton();
             return true;
     }
     return super.onKeyDown(keycode, e);
}
```

Also note that for the back and menu buttons to fire reliably, you need to set `setFocusableInTouchMode` to `true`.  See the [devguide here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) (scroll down to "Touch Mode").